# I get an First and second columns must be entity and time when using Google Visualizer in Rails, why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-visualization

I am using a Ruby wrapper which appears to be correct for using Google Visualizer:

https://github.com/jeremyolliver/gvis

However, I keep getting this particular error:

```
First and second columns must be entity and time
```

However, the data I am passing are entity and time as far as I understand:

```
  <% chart_data = [
 ["Apples", Date.new(1998,1,1), 1000,300,'East'],
 ["Oranges", Date.new(1998,1,1), 950,200,'West'],
 ["Bananas", Date.new(1998,1,1), 300,250,'West'],
 ["Apples", Date.new(1998,2,1), 1200,400,'East'],
 ["Oranges", Date.new(1998,2,1), 950,150,'West'],
 ["Bananas", Date.new(1998,2,1), 788,617,'West']
 ] %>

<% visualization "my_chart", "MotionChart", :width => 600, :height => 400, :html => {:class => "graph_chart"} do |chart| %>
<%# Add the columns that the graph will have
<% chart.string "Fruit" %>
<% chart.date "Date" %>
<% chart.number "Sales" %>
<% chart.number "Expenses" %>
<% chart.string "Location" %>

<% chart.add_rows(chart_data) %>
```

<% end %>

I'm not sure how to debug because I'm not getting enough information to work with in the errors....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should have gone with highcharts :)

The way the source code has it is a little different.

`add_rows` seems to be the method you call on the `chart_object` and then you pass your array of arrays as a method

```
<% chart.add_rows([
        ["Apples", Date.new(1998,1,1), 1000,300,'East'],
        ["Oranges", Date.new(1998,1,1), 950,200,'West'],
        ["Bananas", Date.new(1998,1,1), 300,250,'West'],
        ["Apples", Date.new(1998,2,1), 1200,400,'East'],
        ["Oranges", Date.new(1998,2,1), 950,150,'West'],
        ["Bananas", Date.new(1998,2,1), 788,617,'West']
    ]) %>
```

so this plugin creates a `chart` object with the `add_rows` method for you to pass in your arrays.

```
<% chart.add_rows([this is where you pass your arrays]) %>
```

Comment: do you think highcarts willbe easier and more robust?

Comment: btw, I tried that approach and then tried the one described above -- both seem to have the same error

Comment: if you want to use google's products then it won't be as robust but with highcharts you only need a single js file. You don't need a ruby wrapper and the google visualization kit.

Comment: I see -- I'll probably check out highcharts at some point then...I got it working with Google in the meantime....